# Postdoc job market in relation with PhD topic

Tags: statistics

I switched from Software Engineering to Machine Learning when started my PhD in France. After 3 yrs with 3 (average rank) conference papers, I finished my PhD with an on-going journal manuscript that I'm still working on it with PhD supervisor. I was struggling to get my first postdoc and got it after several months. Now it's coming to an end with no publication after more than 1 yr, and again I'm trying hard to find the next one.

My questions are:

1. Does the PhD topic have a significant impact on academia job opportunity afterward? I got publication and now realize that it is not in "mainstream" as postdoc jobs mostly require "mainstream knowledge". On the other hand, it could have been harder for me to publish during PhD if I chose "mainstream" as I have had no background of it (Statistics). The lack of Statistics knowledge of a Software Engineering guy inconvenienced my 1st postdoc and my job search.
2. How long should it take to convert a Software Engineer to Statistician?
3. Data Science is trendy in general, but does its academia job market become more and more competitive?

Comment: is this about job or academia? what is your plan? what would you like to be?

Comment: Tks Simon, currently job and academia are the same to me, my plan is to become a professor, is it too dreamy?

Comment: Please, your degree is not worthless, good PhD you have, can you find in some other institution outside of France? you need to find lab that can give you a lot of papers, that is only way to secure academia possition

Answer (score 1):

Everything in academia (as most things) becomes more and more competitive. You are facing economic pressures of course. Some academic fields draw a lot of interest because the problems there are seen as useful to solve.

However, I worry that you are chasing a job - any job - rather than a profession. I'd advise you to think about how you want to spend your life  rather than the next job. The economics and the "trendy jobs" are bound to change and it is difficult or impossible to predict what will be "hot" next year.

As to your statistics question, it is relatively easy to learn provided you have an adequate maths background. There are a lot of books. You need at least a bit of the underlying theory (including probability) so that you understand the principles. You also need a grounding in how statistics are applied in scientific endeavors (experiment design). But there are, as I said, plenty of books for that. You needn't try to pursue another degree or anything like that. It is the knowledge you need, not some certification.

Finally, yes, your topic affects your job prospects *in the short term*. However, no one should choose a topic based on what is hot today since it may be lukewarm or cold by the time you finish. Find something satisfying to do and then find a way to do it. But keep some flexibility in your plans so that if you fall into a poor job market for your skills you have other skills you can apply.

I graduated into a very poor job market in mathematics. I quickly taught myself computer programming and later computer science. I had a very successful career after a slow start.

---

Self study in statistics is normally sufficient to *use* statistics for other things. I don't imply it is sufficient (necessarily) to do research *in* statistics itself.

Comment: I can get what you indicate. Actually it is frustrating to read many recruitment requiring stuff of things I have no knowledge of, and I think I would like to follow Data Science, without awareness of a specific profession in this changing world.

Comment: Find a good academic library and read a couple of papers on the topic. If they are too esoteric, find one or two of the papers referenced in them. They may be easier to understand. Just get a feel for whether you think you can talk to the authors intelligently.